# How can I resolve 'from bitly_api import Connection, BitlyError, Error' in pycharm?

Tags: python, api

so I've installed bit_api in Pycharm using the settings tab. 
I run the following code

```
import bitly_api

BITLY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "74e40eae5737852ee2bba8ece28adb3b452208c4"

b = bitly_api.Connection(access_token=BITLY_ACCESS_TOKEN)

response = b.shorten('http://google.com/')
print(response)
```

and get an error as:-

```
from bitly_api import Connection, BitlyError, Error
ImportError: cannot import name 'Connection'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Could possibly be a bug in the library: https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python/issues/39 As mentioned from that github thread, you might want to use https://github.com/ellisonleao/pyshorteners instead since `bitly_api` doesn't seem to have much support.

Comment: i used the following code:-https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/url-shorteners-and-its-api-in-python-set-2/ and now getting requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-ssl.bit.ly', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.5) along with many errors

Comment: Without seeing your code it is hard to know the issue. It could be your access token isn't valid. That error seems to be unrelated to this post since it is dealing with the `pyshorteners` library. I would recommend using their own documentation compared to geeksforgeeks https://pyshorteners.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html#bit-ly

Comment: yeah , the source doesn't matter what I want is to just make a url shortner using python using pyshortner or bitly doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by doing the below steps. In addition, you'll be using your *PyCharm* terminal throughout the below steps.

1. If you've already installed bitly_api, uninstall it by entering the following command in the terminal: `pip uninstall bitly_api`
2. Download the Bitly API module from the following link: [bitly-api-python](https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python). To download the API module, press the green button: **Clone or download** (on the right), and afterwards, press **Download ZIP**.
3. Unzip the downloaded folder into the project directory and navigate into the folder **bitly-api-python-master** by entering `cd bitly-api-python-master`.
4. Install the bitly_api module by entering the command into the terminal: `python setup.py install`.
5. In the terminal, enter your Python shell by entering the command `python` and afterwards, enter `import bitly_api`. If there are no errors, the module was successfully installed (ignore syntax warnings).
6. Run your code again and it should work.